# Apriori and fpgrowth algorithms in weka for association rules mining

Tags: weka, data-mining, apriori

I read that
"Apriori and Fpgrowth will generate the same association rules."
But when I use Apriori and Fpgrowth algorithms in weka. 
Aprior finds some rules and Fpgrowth find no rule!!
Why this happened?

My Data set: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=67323646698703228823

I first Preprocessing: Numeric to nominal.
It is small partition of: http://snap.stanford.edu/class/cs246-data/browsing.txt

That is converted to binominal by zero and one!
Qusetion:
The action or practice of selling additional products or services to existing customers is called cross-selling. Giving product recommendation is one of the examples of cross-selling that are frequently used by online retailers. One simple method to give product recommendations is to recommend products that are frequently browsed together by the customers. Suppose we want to recommend new products to the customer based on the products they have already browsed on the online website. With a Tool using the A-priori algorithm & FP-Growth to find products which are frequently browsed together.llo,
I read that
Hide   Copy Code
Apriori and Fpgrowth will generate the same association rules.
But when I use Apriori and Fpgrowth algorithms in weka. 
Aprior finds some rules and Fpgrowth find no rule!!
Why this happened?
My Data set
Preprocessing: Numeric to nominal

Jj
It is small partition of this
Qusetion:
Hide   Copy Code
The action or practice of selling additional products or services to existing customers is called cross-selling. Giving product recommendation is one of the examples of cross-selling that are frequently used by online retailers. One simple method to give product recommendations is to recommend products that are frequently browsed together by the customers. Suppose we want to recommend new products to the customer based on the products they have already browsed on the online website. With a Tool using the A-priori algorithm & FP-Growth to find products which are frequently browsed together.

Comment: Maybe there is a parameter difference, or a bug. Have you veeified **which is the correct result**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apriori and fpgrowth algorithms in weka](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40988669/apriori-and-fpgrowth-algorithms-in-weka)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change *positiveIndex* parameter to 1. It will work!

Comment: Thanks so much! It works perfectly! Why?? What is positive Index??

Comment: It is index of the attribute value to consider as positive in normal dense instances. Index 1 is always used for sparse instances. As your dataset is sparse, you should set it as 1. And if your dataset is dense, you should increase it. if it was useful, please set this solution as answer